# Need help rescuing Kubuntu 19.10 from graphics snafu

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, kubuntu, xorg

I've been happily running Kubuntu 19.10 for the last year. This is a core i7 system with 24gigs of RAM and a GEFORCE GTX 1050ti video card.

I stumbled into the KDE System Settings dialog for Drivers. This page listed several nVidia drivers and the X.org Nouveau display driver which is what I had been using. But the "nvidia-driver-435" was marked as "recommended". Stupidly I selected that driver which downloaded the software and rebooted the system.

Of course, it got to the Kubuntu splash screen and froze. I have tried adding "nomodeset" to the Grub startup configuration. I have purged the nVidia drivers (sudo apt-get autoremove --purge nvidia-*) and reinstalled them. I have purged them AND the Nouveau driver (sudo apt-get autoremove -purge xserver-xorg-video-nouveau) and only reinstalled the nouveau driver. None of this worked, the system boots to the Kubuntu splash screen and then freezes on a blank screen.

Of cource I can access the command line from another terminal session or boot the system using the Kubuntu install CD. My question is; how to I reinstate the Nouveau graphics driver without access to the KDE graphical interface?

Answer (score 0):

After beating my head against this problem for a day, I stumbled across my own solution. I had uninstalled and reinstalled the nouveau and nVidia drivers available (390, 430, 435) in the repositories multiple times in various combinations without success.

Then, searching on the nVidia site I came across the latest driver; [440](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/159360/en-us) as a manual install .run file. I downloaded it to my 19.10 installation using a live USB and installed it from my the command line. It complained a couple of times, but I finally got it installed and KDE came back to life.

An interesting side effect of this is that, during the install, it asked if I wanted to install 32-bit libraries (yes), and now Steam, which I could never get working in 19.10, works just fine.